# Setup Stripe debits from a connect account

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

I'm not sure if anyone else has set this up yet since it's in public beta (I think it's been in public beta since at least January though) but I'm trying to set up Stripe connect debits so that we can back charge connect users for over payment as well as fees.

I've followed the tutorial here - https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits.

Here is my code:

```
transfer = Stripe::Transfer.create(
 {
  amount: 1000,
  currency: 'usd',
  destination: ENV['STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID']
 },
 stripe_account: #{STRIPE_CONNECT_MERCHANT_ID}
)
```

The error I get is "Can not transfer funds from a Standard account."

The merchant account is an express account but our platform is a standard account (which I don't think it can be an express, nor would we want that).

Any advice helps!

Comment: Hmm, `destination` should be _your_ account ID(that you can get with a `Account::retrieve()` call), and `stripe_account` should be the merchant account(the Express account), the error makes it sounds like you have them reversed?

Comment: @karllekko ty you for the response. It ended up being silliness on my part. I had some production users data in my local database from (debugging at an early time) but it still allowed me to use the Account::retrieve() function successfully. Long story short it was returning the above error because it couldn't find that merchant account because it was a production account.